# I need to access "Issues in Feature" stories, but don't see how

Tags: api, rest, jira

I don't see a way to access "Issues in Feature" stories. Can someone point me in the right direction? Any help is greatly appreciated!

I'm using the JIRA latest API (I think 7.1.1), and can make other calls to get info from Jira, just haven't found a way to get the "child" stories from this section.

Answer (score 0):

By *Issues In Feature* I assume you want to search for Stories (or other issue types) linked to an issue of type Feature.

If you use an add-on like [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview), you get access to additional JQL functions that allow you to query for issues linked to each other. Look [here for its documentation](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/jql-functions.html#_issue_links).

The JQL you end up with can also be used in REST API calls.